# Move/share pinned tab between windows in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, pinning

Suppose the following scenarios.

1. Open firefox (window A).
2. Pin tab X
3. Open new firefox window (B)
4. Close A
5. Close B
6. Open firefox
7. No X tab

If I switch steps 5 and 6, pinned tab will be there.

Is there an option or addon to either move pinned tav X to Window B, when I close A, or at least have X opened at step 7?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is perfectly as expected. If you have "show my windows and tabs from last time" selected for "when Firefox starts" in options, Firefox opens those for the **first** Firefox instance you open and **then discards them**. Subsequent instances open with the home page.

When you close a window Firefox saves the list of open tabs for next time. When you close a second window after the first one **that first list is overwritten**. That's the reason you lost the pinned tab, and the reason the pinned tab is preserved when you close A after closing B.

It would be possible to retain the list of open tabs even after a first instance starts, so that the second instance also opens those tabs, but I'm not aware of an add-on which does that.

BTW, you don't have to pin the tab to have it reopened. See Options | General | Startup.